# How to use" document.getElementById('file').click()" in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I searched for a below javascript code and I want to use it in Reactjs:

```html
    <input type="button" id="loadFileXml" value="loadXml" onclick="document.getElementById('file').click();" />
    <input type="file" style="display:none;" id="file" name="file"/>
```

In order to use it in Reactjs, I changed it to:

```html
    <input type="button" id="loadFileXml" value="loadXml" onClick={document.getElementById('file').click()} />
    <input type="file" style="display:none;" id="file" name="file"/>
```

But I got error message `Cannot read property 'click' of null`.
Could somebody help me figure out how to write the write code for that.

Thanks so much.

Comment: An onclick to trigger a click is odd in any case, but especially in react.  React generally doesn't use document.getElementById to get things done.  Maybe you would be benefit from sharing more about your broader problem rather than try to make this approach work.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use react js in this way. First, you can use a state for the display property. Suppose there is a class component. 
I wrote it with my hand, it could be a typo.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

class Example extends Component {
 state = {
  isVisible : true ; 
} 

  changeVisible = () => {

    this.setState({

       isVisible : !this.state.isVisible // this working like a toggle button 
    })

   }

render (){
    return(
   <div>
        <button onClick = {this.changeVisible}> Change Visible </button>
        {
           //This section may be the item that you want to be visible or not
           isVisible ? <h1>I am Visible </h1> : null

        }
   </div>

)
}


} 
  export default Example;
```

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I personally don't think you should be hiding the file input control and delegating the click to another element.

That said, the way to do this with React is to get a reference to the file input element using the `ref` property and [`React.createRef`](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html) method:

> Refs are created using `React.createRef()` and attached to React elements via the `ref` attribute. Refs are commonly assigned to an instance property when a component is constructed so they can be referenced throughout the component.

Demo:

```js
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.fileRef = React.createRef();
  }
  
  handleClick = () => {
    const fileElem = this.fileRef.current;
    if (fileElem) {
      fileElem.click();
    }
  }
  
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.handleClick}>button</button>
        <input ref={this.fileRef} type="file" style={{display: 'none'}} name="file" />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <MyComponent />,
  document.getElementById('app')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```